# how to filter scores from the nested document using (MONGO DB OR PYMONGO).if all the scores of a particular person is greater than 40

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, pymongo, nested-documents

```js
[
  {
    "_id": 5,
    "name": "Wilburn Spiess",
    "scores": [
      {
        "score": 44.87186330181261,
        "type": "exam"
      },
      {
        "score": 25.72395114668016,
        "type": "quiz"
      },
      {
        "score": 63.42288310628662,
        "type": "homework"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": 6,
    "name": "Jenette Flanders",
    "scores": [
      {
        "score": 37.32285459166097,
        "type": "exam"
      },
      {
        "score": 28.32634976913737,
        "type": "quiz"
      },
      {
        "score": 81.57115318686338,
        "type": "homework"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": 7,
    "name": "Salena Olmos",
    "scores": [
      {
        "score": 90.37826509157176,
        "type": "exam"
      },
      {
        "score": 42.48780666956811,
        "type": "quiz"
      },
      {
        "score": 96.52986171633331,
        "type": "homework"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: what is the expected output? you want to keep the documents that all scores > 40 for example the last one?

Comment: i want to know if a particular person scores lies in between 40 to 60 .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Query1

- keep a document, if the min score> 40 (all scores > 40)

[Playmongo](https://cmql.org/playmongo/?q=63147ce578a49d878285149b)

```js
aggregate(
[{"$match": {"$expr": {"$gt": [{"$min": "$scores.score"}, 40]}}}])
```

Query2

- all scores for `>40` and `<70`
- and change the array to have the type as key as your expected ouput

[Playmongo](https://cmql.org/playmongo/?q=63161cf878a49d878285149d)

```js
aggregate(
[{"$match": 
   {"$expr": 
     {"$and": 
       [{"$gt": [{"$min": "$scores.score"}, 40]},
         {"$lt": [{"$max": "$scores.score"}, 70]}]}}},
 {"$set": 
   {"scores": 
     {"$arrayToObject": 
       [{"$map": 
           {"input": "$scores",
            "as": "s",
            "in": {"k": "$$s.type", "v": "$$s.score"}}}]}}},
 {"$replaceRoot": 
   {"newRoot": 
     {"$mergeObjects": [{"name": "$name", "_id": "$_id"}, "$scores"]}}}])
```

Comment: {'_id': ObjectId('6231ddd19855c49b8d7536d3'), 'name': 'Gena Riccio', 'Exam': 57.58395308948619, 'Quiz': 57.2413500951588, 'HomeWork': 42.9347177989952}                          i need the output to be like this.

Comment: thanks ur code worked.if u can help me. i have an another doubt how to filter it greater than 40 and less than 70

Comment: i updated it for 40> <70 and i changed it to have the input you like, with replace-root and merge-documents you could get exactly the output you want, but i dont think there is a reason to make it more complicated.

Comment: also if you have only 3 types of exams maybe you dont need array, maybe a nested document would be simple, and access with paths

Comment: thanks for ur help.i have been trying it for 2 days.i wanted to keep it in same format :)

Comment: ok i added one more stage the replace-root, to produce exactly the output you want gl